# How can I find out what class each of the columns in the probabilities output correspond to using Keras for a multi-class classification problem?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, image-recognition

I'm using transfer learning to build an image recognition model using a pre-trained VGG network in Keras and excluding the final fully-connected layer to get the output weights.  I'm then using these output weights to feed into my new model which has a few layers along with a new fully-connected layer of my own that I'm training. The fully-connected layer maps to the number of output classes that I'm trying to predict.

Everything is working fine.  However, when I run:

```
results = model.predict(img_tensor)
```

I get output probabilities corresponding to each class, similar to the below:

```
print(results)

[[0.1426621  0.6193871  0.23795079]
 [0.11187755 0.6208466  0.2672758 ]
 [0.10050113 0.3768951  0.52260375]
 [0.1338948  0.59470254 0.27140263]
 [0.06612041 0.69726    0.2366195 ]
 [0.12080433 0.495977   0.38321865]]
```

How can I find out what class each of the columns in the probabilities output correspond to?

Does Keras have anything built-in to identify which column of the output probabilities corresponds to which class?

Answer (score 5):

The `class_indices` attribute in Keras’ `flow_from_directory(directory)` creates a dictionary of the classes and their index in the output array:

> classes: optional list of class subdirectories (e.g. `[‘dogs’, ‘cats’]`). Default: None. If not provided, the list of classes will be
> automatically inferred from the subdirectory names/structure under
> directory, where each subdirectory will be treated as a different
> class (and the order of the classes, which will map to the label
> indices, will be alphanumeric). The dictionary containing the mapping
> from class names to class indices can be obtained via the attribute
> `class_indices`.

[Source](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

I would be interested to see how people have incorporated this into their workflow/scripts though...

Comment: Does this mean that if I have only 2 subdirectories "cats" and "dogs" then it will create a class 0 corresponding to "cats" and a class "1" corresponding to "dogs" simply because "cats" comes first in alphabetical order?

Comment: Can I change output to smth like [[cat:0.14], [dog:086]]? And how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can then select the most probable classes using the `probas_to_classes()` utility function. Example:

```
y_proba = model.predict(x)
y_classes = keras.np_utils.probas_to_classes(y_proba)
```

This is equivalent to `model.predict_classes(x)` on the Sequential model.

When Using Generators,

```
generator= train_datagen.flow_from_directory("train", batch_size=batch_size)
 label_map = (generator.class_indices)
```

The label_map variable is a dictionary,
Then from this the relation can be derived between the probability scores and class names.

Basically, you can create this dictionary by this code.

```
from glob import glob
class_names = glob("*") # Reads all the folders in which images are present
class_names = sorted(class_names) # Sorting them
name_id_map = dict(zip(class_names, range(len(class_names))))
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Keras doesn't have something called `np_utils` btw..

Comment: Ahh, I am not sure about that as of now, maybe it has.